# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) when try to play audio file

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, audio, memory

I am trying to create a Morse translator for both IOS and Android using Xamarin and C#. I have tried all kinds of things and in the end used Autofac because I needed to reference main project to android and back. That is so because I have Interface in my main project

```
namespace SuperMorse
{
    public interface ISoundService
    {
        void PlayDotSound();
        void PlayDashSound();

        int dot { get; set; }
        int dash { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and a class in Android project

```
namespace SuperMorse.Droid
{
    public class SoundService : ISoundService
    {
        public int dot { get; set; }
        public int dash { get; set; }

        public SoundService()
        {
            dot = Android.App.Application.Context.Resources.GetIdentifier("dot", "raw", Android.App.Application.Context.PackageName);
            dash = Android.App.Application.Context.Resources.GetIdentifier("dash", "raw", Android.App.Application.Context.PackageName);
        }
        public void PlayDotSound()
        {
            var fd = Android.App.Application.Context.Assets.OpenFd("dot.mp3");
            MediaPlayer dotPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            dotPlayer.SetDataSource(fd.FileDescriptor, fd.StartOffset, fd.Length);
            dotPlayer.Prepare();
            dotPlayer.Start();
        }
        public void PlayDashSound()
        {
            var fd = Android.App.Application.Context.Assets.OpenFd("dash.mp3");
            MediaPlayer dashPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            dashPlayer.SetDataSource(fd.FileDescriptor, fd.StartOffset, fd.Length);
            dashPlayer.Prepare();
            dashPlayer.Start();
        }

    }
}
```

so when I call the PlaySounds functions back in my MainPage function I get a strange error in my terminal: **Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x7ffc7ad11fb8 in tid 31167 (name.supermorse), pid 31167 (name.supermorse)**. I debugged it and it seems the error occurs when the line  var fd = Android.App.Application.Context.Assets.OpenFd("dot.mp3"); from the SoundService.cs runs.... or a similiar one for the dash. Any idea how to fix?

Tried reading my audio files and changing their format

Comment: ah and yes I am sorry. METHODS! not functions. Sorry

Comment: Just [edit] your question if you want to correct or add something.

Comment: have you tried adding any exception handling?  What purpose do `dot` and `dash` serve?  You never use them.  Why are you opening the asset and creating a new instance of `MediaPlayer` **every single time** you want to play a sound?  This seems very inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have create a new sample to test your code. And the `dot.mp3` was displayed when I run the project.

In the Page.cs:

```
private void button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ISoundService soundService = DependencyService.Get<ISoundService>();
   soundService.PlayDotSound();
}
```

The interface:

```
namespace AppTest
{
    public interface ISoundService
    {
        void PlayDotSound();
        void PlayDashSound();

        int dot { get; set; }
        int dash { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The android dependency service:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(AppTest.Droid.SoundService))]
namespace AppTest.Droid
{
    public class SoundService : ISoundService
    {
        public int dot { get; set; }
        public int dash { get; set; }

        public SoundService()
        {
            dot = Android.App.Application.Context.Resources.GetIdentifier("dot", "raw", Android.App.Application.Context.PackageName);
            dash = Android.App.Application.Context.Resources.GetIdentifier("dash", "raw", Android.App.Application.Context.PackageName);
        }
        public void PlayDotSound()
        {
            var fd = Android.App.Application.Context.Assets.OpenFd("dot.mp3");
            MediaPlayer dotPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            dotPlayer.SetDataSource(fd.FileDescriptor, fd.StartOffset, fd.Length);
            dotPlayer.Prepare();
            dotPlayer.Start();
        }
        public void PlayDashSound()
        {
            var fd = Android.App.Application.Context.Assets.OpenFd("dash.mp3");
            MediaPlayer dashPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            dashPlayer.SetDataSource(fd.FileDescriptor, fd.StartOffset, fd.Length);
            dashPlayer.Prepare();
            dashPlayer.Start();
        }

    }
}
```

And the file in the Assets folder:

[image]

In addition, the build action of the dot.mp3 is **AndroidAsset**.

Comment: omg Thanks
I don't know why but for some reason I thought that the audio files had to be in the ...Droid>Resources>raw